# "Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object" with multi_query and store_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been tasked to troubleshoot the following bit of code, but I can't figure out what is causing the fatal error. 
A `selectQuery` would be a query with multiple results (e.g., `select id, metric, text from protocols`) and I'm trying to parse each row within the `while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){` loop that is called in the error. I have a feeling it's related to `store_result` or `multi_query` but I can't find any related stackoverflow question. I've found [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) in the PHP manual which seems to be what the code is based off of, but nothing in the comments have helped.

Error: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object in script.php`

I appreciate any insight.

```
$IS_DEBUG = false ; // Screen output debug flag TODO - this might be a better command-line switch ... someday, maybe ...
$COMMON_WORD_LIST = array(
"a" => 1,"about" => 1,"after" => 1,"all" => 1,"also" => 1,"an" => 1,"and" => 1,"any" => 1,"as" => 1,
"at" => 1,"back" => 1,"be" => 1,"because" => 1,"but" => 1,"by" => 1,"can" => 1,"come" => 1,"could" => 1,
"day" => 1,"do" => 1,"even" => 1,"first" => 1,"for" => 1,"from" => 1,"get" => 1,"give" => 1,"go" => 1,
"good" => 1,"have" => 1,"he" => 1,"her" => 1,"him" => 1,"his" => 1,"how" => 1,"i" => 1,"if" => 1,
"in" => 1,"into" => 1,"it" => 1,"its" => 1,"just" => 1,"know" => 1,"like" => 1,"look" => 1,"make" => 1,
"me" => 1,"most" => 1,"my" => 1,"new" => 1,"no" => 1,"not" => 1,"now" => 1,"of" => 1,"on" => 1,"one" => 1,
"only" => 1,"or" => 1,"other" => 1,"our" => 1,"out" => 1,"over" => 1,"people" => 1,"say" => 1,"see" => 1,
"she" => 1,"so" => 1,"some" => 1,"take" => 1,"than" => 1,"that" => 1,"the" => 1,"their" => 1,"them" => 1,
"then" => 1,"there" => 1,"these" => 1,"they" => 1,"think" => 1,"this" => 1,"time" => 1,"to" => 1,"two" => 1,
"up" => 1,"us" => 1,"use" => 1,"want" => 1,"way" => 1,"we" => 1,"well" => 1,"what" => 1,"when" => 1,
"which" => 1,"who" => 1,"will" => 1,"with" => 1,"work" => 1,"would" => 1,"year" => 1,"you" => 1,"your" => 1,
"td" => 1,"p" => 1,"the" => 1,"valign" => 1,"top" => 1,"width" => 1,"strong" => 1,"tr" => 1,"of" => 1,
"to" => 1,"or" => 1,"a" => 1,"and" => 1,"bottom" => 1,"you" => 1,"is" => 1,"for" => 1,"in" => 1,"nbsp" => 1,
"center" => 1,"align" => 1,"bgcolor" => 1,"yes" => 1,"class" => 1,"no" => 1,"if" => 1,"per" => 1,"sub" => 1,
"be" => 1,"bfbfbf" => 1,"that" => 1,"i" => 1,"not" => 1,"b" => 1,"font" => 1,"on" => 1,"have" => 1,
"vertical" => 1,"u" => 1,"with" => 1,"are" => 1,"colspan" => 1,"at" => 1,"your" => 1,"as" => 1,"e" => 1,
"more" => 1,"this" => 1,"know" => 1,"c" => 1,"don't" => 1,"other" => 1,"reg" => 1,"did" => 1,"how" => 1,
"nowrap" => 1,"than" => 1,"g" => 1,"em" => 1,"li" => 1,"by" => 1,"color" => 1,"table" => 1,"from" => 1,
"d" => 1,"time" => 1,"ff" => 1,"should" => 1,"used" => 1,"it" => 1,"when" => 1,"do" => 1,"has" => 1,
"an" => 1,"one" => 1,"month" => 1,"past" => 1,"was" => 1,"br" => 1,"div" => 1,"ccff" => 1,"jpg" => 1, "s" => 1
);

// function to check for common words
function isCommonWord($word) {
    global $COMMON_WORD_LIST;
    if (array_key_exists($word,$COMMON_WORD_LIST)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function queryField($con, $selectQuery, $field, $indexField){
    if ($con->multi_query($selectQuery)) {
        do {
            /* store first result set */
            if ($result = $con->store_result()) {
                //if(!is_object($results)){
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
                        /* text that needs to be parsed will be first column of query */
                        if($indexField=="KEYWORD"){
                            $protocol_text = strtolower($row[0]);
                            $protocol_text = preg_replace("/\n/", " ", $protocol_text);
                            $protocol_text = preg_replace("/\W+\s+/", " ", $protocol_text);
                            $protocol_text = preg_replace("/\s+\d+\s+/", " ", $protocol_text);
                            $protocol_text = preg_replace("/\s+\W+/", " ", $protocol_text);
                            $protocol_text = preg_replace("/\<p\>/", "", $protocol_text);
                            $protocol_text = preg_replace("/\<\/p\>/", "", $protocol_text);
                            $protocol_text = preg_replace("/\./", "", $protocol_text);
                            $protocol_text = preg_replace("/[\/\[\]\{\}_\)\(]+/", " ", $protocol_text);
                            $protocol_text = trim($protocol_text);

                            $measure_id=$row[1];
                            ##################################################################################
                            # ALGORITHM ######################################################################
                            ##################################################################################
                            # parse words
                            $textSize=strlen($protocol_text);
                            echo "TEXT_SIZE||".$textSize.PHP_EOL;
                            $offset=0;
                            $match_count=0;

                            while(preg_match("/([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']+)/", $protocol_text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)) {
                                ... PROPRIETARY ...
                                if (isCommonWord($matches[0])==0) {
                                    $fullTextInsert = "insert into full_text_indexes (MEASURE_ID, WORD, MATCH_START, MATCH_LENGTH, MATCH_NUMBER, FIELD_INDEXED) values ($measure_id, '$matches[0]', $match_start, $match_length, $match_count, '$indexField')";
                                    $result = sendQuery($con, $fullTextInsert);
                                    if($result) {
                                        echo "SUCCESS||".$fullTextInsert.PHP_EOL;
                                    }else{
                                        die("FAIL||".$fullTextInsert );
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }else{

                        }
                    }
                //}
                $result->free();
            }
            /* print divider */
            if ($con->more_results()) {
                printf("-----------------\n");
            }
        } while ($con->next_result());
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I never use `multi_query()`. It makes the code more complex, and it introduces a potential vector for making SQL injection vulnerabilities much more harmful. As the former engineering manager for MySQL told me, "there's no reason for multi-query to exist."

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: That bizarre `preg_replace` ritual you have there is not only completely ineffective against stopping XSS and SQL injection, but there's a way to get the results you need with far fewer lines of code. `bind_param` on insert and [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on display.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. I switched over to the object oriented style and used prepared statements as advised, and it fixed the issue in the process. As for switching from `multi_query`, that will have to wait until I have more time. Thanks all for your help. @tadman, if you'd like to create an answer with your previous comments, I'll approve.

Comment: Those aren't really an answer so much as general advice that helps you avoid a lot of common pitfalls. If you came up with a specific fix here, that would be worth posting as a self-answer.